# Batch writing to a file returns with ECHO is OFF

Tags: batch-file

This never happened for me before, and I don't exactly understand why.

I used this code to set a variable from the text file:

```
set Drive=E
for /f "Delims=" %%a in (%Drive%:\Data\TestAttempt.txt) do (
set TEST=%%a
)
```

Then I tried to +1 to the %TEST%:

```
set /A TEST=TEST+1
```

At last I tried to put the new Variable into the same text file:

```
cd %Drive%:\Data
echo %TEST%> TestAttempt.txt
```

It worked before, and now I won't work. I don't understand why... It still returns ECHO is OFF. in the TestAttempt.txt file. It should be 2.

I have tried to create a space between %TEST% and >, but then I can't use +1.

Thanks.. :)

Comment: Well I' use `set /a Test+=1` and if if the echo is inside the parentheses of the do you'll need delayed expansion to get current values and not the parse time value. See [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
echo %TEST%> TestAttempt.txt
```

to

```
>TestAttempt.txt echo %TEST%
```

A digit directly before a redirector redirects that device # (0=stdin,1=stdout,2=stderr)

Hence your code reduced to `echo` which reports the `echo` status (on or off).

`echo(%potentiallyemptyvar%` will produce an empty line if `potentiallyemptyvar` is indeed empty.